# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined react-redux todo app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi Im trying to build a todo app and trying to add todos in todo list but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

here is the error code:

```
   4 | function TodoList() {
   5 |   const list = useSelector((state) => state.todoList.text);
   6 |   return (
>  7 |     <div>
   8 |     {list.map((todo)=>{
   9 |         <li>todo</li>
  10 |     })}
```

here is the TodoList.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const TodoList = () => {
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.todoList.text);
  return (
    <div>
    {list.map((todo)=>{
        <li>todo</li>
    })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

here is the index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { TodoReducer,TodoListReducer } from "./redux/reducers";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todoList: TodoListReducer,
  todos: TodoReducer
});

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>{" "}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

here is the reducers.js:

```
import { SET_VALUE } from "./actions";
import {ADD_TODO} from "./actions"

let initial_state = [{
    text:""
}]
export const TodoReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return [{
                text: action.text,
            }]
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const TodoListReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                text: action.text
            }

            default:
                return state;
    }
}
```

Actually I'm a new coder so I might have a lot of mistakes :). Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`state.todoList` is an array of object. So just update like this:

```
const list = useSelector((state) => state.todoList);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! But now I get this error:

 TypeError: list.map is not a function

There is no problem until I write anything to my bar. When I write a character in the bar then suddenly I get the error code.

Comment: Should return `return [{ text:action.text }]`

Answer (score 1):

The initial state dont have the property 'todoList' so that state.todoList is undefined.

Set a default value for it like `let initial_state = {todoList:[{text:""}]}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention! I changed my code as you said but I get this error when I changed the code: TypeError: list.map is not a function